# Generating exponential distribution numbers, but in real time

Tags: c++

I have a task, to implement a simulation of an infinite FIFO queue, with n workers.

Customers come in time generated by exponential distribution, and worker's work time is generated by Poisson distribution. There is a thing that I don't understand. For the first time, for testing I wrote my app with two another algorithms - I was just generating random numbers between 1 and 5 (workers were working for 1-5 seconds at random) and clients coming at the same rate.

Now, I'm facing the problem:

Can these values: exponential and Poisson be generated ONE BY ONE, in a loop - for example:

1. I generate one value
2. Put the worker to work for 'value' time
3. I generate a second exponentially larger value

Or this is only possible by generating one array at the beginning?

I found this algorithm:

```
#include <random>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
       std::mt19937 rng( std::time(0) ) ;
       std::exponential_distribution<double> distrib(2.0) ;
       for( int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; ++i ) std::cout << std::fixed <<     distrib(rng) << '\n' ;
}
```

And it generates numbers, but I'm not sure if it will work. (And I don't know, how to generate bigger values).

Comment: What do you mean exactly with generating an exponential value? A value that is exponentially bigger?

Comment: Yes. I need to generate numbers to simulate a shopping queue - workers work shorter in the morning, and longer at 3 PM.

But I can't generate them at once (at the beginning of the program) but I need to generate one, put a worker to work and when it finishes, generate a new number.